# How to get user phone number in google login api?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

**Here is my code:**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");
$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
$user = $service->userinfo->get(); //get user info
echo "<pre>";
print_r($user);
die;
```

**The result is:**

```
/*
Google_Service_Oauth2_Userinfoplus Object
(
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
            [familyName] => family_name
            [givenName] => given_name
            [verifiedEmail] => verified_email
        )

    [email] => MyEmailName@gmail.com
    [familyName] => Martinish
    [gender] => 
    [givenName] => Martin
    [hd] => 
    [id] => 11150231528512531xxx
    [link] => https://plus.google.com/111502315285125311xxx
    [locale] => en
    [name] => Martin Martinish
    [picture] => https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-fVHMRUGw5z4/xxx/xxx/IhHnvxaOyAw/photo.jpg
    [verifiedEmail] => 1
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
            [verified_email] => 1
            [given_name] => Martin
            [family_name] => Martinish
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Now I also need to get user's cell phone (mobile) number. How can I do that?

---

I've added these scopes: (according to [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes))

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read
```

But still the result is exactly the same. Anyway, any idea how can I retrieve/achieve a contact *(preferably mobile number)* info?

Comment: Hello,you got any succes for get user mobile number from gmail login